# Moment.js - incorrect time zone with multiple instance/time zone aware countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, countdown, countdowntimer

I'm using jQuery.countdown and moment.js to create a multiple instance/time zone aware countdown timer. Everything works except the time zone. Throwing in the time zone changes the countdown to GMT, not the zone that I specify. No matter what time zone I choose, the timer stays at GMT.

I'm using the latest version of moment.js and moment-timezone-with-data-2012-2022.js. I've spent way too much time trying to figure this out, please help!

```js
$(function(){
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
        var finalDate = moment.tz(finalDate, 'America/Los_Angeles');
        $this.countdown(finalDate.toDate(), function(event) {
            var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
            $(this).html(event.strftime('Expires in ' + totalHours + ' hr %-M min'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>

  <div data-countdown="04/18/2018 00:00:00"></div>
  <div data-countdown="04/19/2018 00:00:00"></div>
  <div data-countdown="04/20/2018 00:00:00"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be from this warning which is shown in the console:

> Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.

This is caused by your non-standard date format that you are passing to moment without telling moment the incoming format. To fix just specify the incoming format. as described here: [Parsing in Zone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) and shown in the code below.

```js
$(function(){
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), 
            countdown = $(this).data('countdown');

        // set the incoming date format as the 2nd paramater to the constructor
        var finalDate = moment.tz(countdown, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss', 'America/Los_Angeles');
        
        $this.countdown(finalDate.toDate(), function(event) {
            var totalHours = event.offset.totalDays * 24 + event.offset.hours;
            $(this).html(event.strftime('Expires in ' + totalHours + ' hr %-M min'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>

<div data-countdown="04/18/2018 00:00:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="04/19/2018 00:00:00"></div>
<div data-countdown="04/20/2018 00:00:00"></div>
```